# Scaling images with js using binary subdivison algorithm

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, image-size

Can I scaling images in js/canvas using custom algorithm, like binary subdivison or another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes...You can use html5 canvas to do custom image subdivision.**

If you are doing simple binary subdivision, you can use the extended version of `context.drawImage` to clip each tile from the main canvas and scale any subdivision as desired. See the example below.

**Non-binary subdivisions are a bit tricky...**

Your custom algorithm must generate the vertices or curve control points of each individual path of the desired subdivision.

The technique is to repeat this process for every element of the subdivision:

- Create a temporary canvas: var tempCanvas=document.createElement('canvas');
- Scale the canvas using `tempContext.scale`
- Define a subpath on the image using context path commands: `tempContext.beginPath ...`
- Restrict future drawing into that path using `tempContext.clip`
- Draw the image onto the canvas using `tempContext.drawImage`.  Since a clipping region has been defined, the image *will only be drawn inside the path you have defined*.
- Use this temporary canvas as an image source to draw the subdivision on your main canvas: `mainContext.drawImage(tempCanvas,x,y)`

Here's example code and a Demo of simple binary subdivision with scaling:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var subdivisions=[];
var subdivisionIndex=0;

subdivisions.push({
  x:0,y:0,
  width:174/2,height:110/2,
  scale:1.00,maxScale:2.00,scaleDirection:1
});
subdivisions.push({
  x:174/2,y:0,
  width:174/2,height:110/2,
  scale:1.00,maxScale:2.00,scaleDirection:1
});
subdivisions.push({
  x:0,y:110/2,
  width:174/2,height:110/2,
  scale:1.00,maxScale:2.00,scaleDirection:1
});
subdivisions.push({
  x:174/2,y:110/2,
  width:174/2,height:110/2,
  scale:1.00,maxScale:2.00,scaleDirection:1
});


var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/cars.jpg";
function start(){
  animate();
}

function draw(s){
  var x=s.x;
  var y=s.y;
  var w=s.width;
  var h=s.height;
  var scaledW=w*s.scale;
  var scaledH=h*s.scale;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.drawImage(
    img,        // clip from img
    x,y,w,h,    // clip a subdivision 
    x,y,scaledW,scaledH  // draw the subdivision scaled
  )
}

function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  var s=subdivisions[subdivisionIndex];
  draw(s);


  if(s.scaleDirection>0){
    s.scale*=1.02;
    if(s.scale>s.maxScale){s.scaleDirection=-1;}
  }else{
    s.scale/=1.02;
    if(s.scale<1.00){
      s.scale=1.00;
      s.scaleDirection=1;
      subdivisionIndex++;
      if(subdivisionIndex>subdivisions.length-1){
        subdivisionIndex=0; 
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<h4>Scaling subdivisions of a binary subdivided image</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```